# Hiding an element in a drop down list based on a condition in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want to hide the option "Chad" in the drop down list if the user type "Cha" in the input field. 
For that I wrote the following code using angular js and javascript and what should I include within the if clause there? 
Is there any other method to perform this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">   
</script>                 

<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<form>
First Name: 
<input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
</form>

<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="name for name in names">
</select>

</div>

<script>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.firstname = "Cha";

//assigning elements to the drop down list
$scope.names = ["Chad", "Ab", "Za"];

if($scope.firstname=="Cha"{

 //new code segment here
}

});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this can be achieved using splice() method in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js">   
</script>                 

<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <form>
            First Name: 
            <input type="text"  ng-change="inputUpdate(firstname)" ng-model="firstname">
        </form>

        <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="name for name in names">
        </select>

    </div>

    <script>

        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
            // $scope.firstname = "Cha";

//assigning elements to the drop down list
$scope.names1 = ["Chad", "Ab", "Za"];
$scope.names = ["Chad", "Ab", "Za"];

$scope.names2 = ["Ab", "Za"];

$scope.inputUpdate = function(name){
    if (name == 'Chad') {
        $scope.names = $scope.names2;
    } else{
        $scope.names = $scope.names1;
    }

}

// if($scope.firstname=="Cha"{

//  //new code segment here
// }

});



</script>
</body>
</html>
```